# Calender Not Validating Month and day only Year

Tags: java, swing, date, calendar

I have an action button that is supposed to check the expire date for the application during login:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  Calendar expiredate = Calendar.getInstance();
  expiredate.set(2012, 10, 10);
  if (ae.getSource() == button) {
    char[] temp_pwd = t_pass.getPassword();
    String pwd = null;
    pwd = String.copyValueOf(temp_pwd);

    if (db.checkLogin(t_name.getText(), pwd)) {
      try {
        if (Calendar.getInstance().after(expiredate)) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "License has Expired\n Please Re-new the License from the Provider", "Re-new License", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          t_name.setText("");
          t_pass.setText("");
          t_name.requestFocus();
          return;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have logged in successfully. Click OK to Continue", "Success",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        MainFrame page = new MainFrame();
        page.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(false);
      } catch(Exception ai){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ai, "Exception",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      }
    } else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed!\nWrong Username or password", "Failed!!",
      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
      t_name.setText("");
      t_pass.setText("");
      t_name.requestFocus();
      return;
    }
  }//if
}//method
```

The problem is that the system date is 17th October 2012. Apparently the login still happens. But when I change the 2012 to 2011 as the Expire date, the license validation happens. What could be the issue that the system is ignoring the 10th October 2012 date?

Comment: Sidenote: use `expiredate.set(2012, 09, 10);` to express the 10.10.2012. Month 's are zero-based...

Comment: I think You are right. I did not realize that Months Calculate from 0. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Month constant `10` is for November. `NOVEMBER = 10` so you are setting month as November.

You should use

```
expiredate.set(2012, Calendar.OCTOBER, 10);
```

Always use month constants provided in [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for such usage because month starts from `0` in java. So it avoids confusion.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is, that the month-value of Calender is 0-based. This means, that your expire-Date is the 10th of November.

10th of October would be:

```
expiredate.set(2012, 9 , 10);
```

Hope this helped

Comment: Yes it did help Alot ..I should have Noticed that